# Intellij IDEA how to auto-generate non-javadoc comment block?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

In Eclipse, when adding javadoc comment blocks to the methods of an implementation class(of some interface) whose interface is in the same project, I can type /* (a slash followed by an asterisk) and then press enter and that immediately generates a non-javadoc comment atop that method which references the javadoc of the interface that that class implements using the @see annotation. How can I achieve this behavior in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4761.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Does this mean that the feature was first requested in 2005 and is yet to be implemented?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, I am new to youtrack.jetbrains and wasn't sure how to interpret the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write `/**` and press **ENTER** key

**For the complete implementation:**

Add below code above your method in interface. `@link` is your equivalent to `@see`.

```
 /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * This printHello method is .......... you write explanation here
         * {@link com.example.uddhav.memoryuse.MyInterface}
* I provided absolute reference of MyInterface here 
         */
        public void printHello(String str); /* your method */
```

On your class, which implements interface, you do **right click > generate > override methods > check "copy javadoc"**.

**Example**:

**Interface**

```
    public interface MyInterface {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * {@link com.example.uddhav.memoryuse.MyInterface}  
     * This printHello method is ..........
     */
    public void printHello(String str);

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * This printUddhav method is ..........
     */

    public void printUddhav(String strr);

    public void printGautam(String strr);

}
```

**Class**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{
/* right click > generate > override methods > copy JavaDoc */
/* you are done */

/* I generated these below */

 /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * {@link MyInterface}
     * This printHello method is ..........
     *
     * @param str
     */
    @Override
    public void printHello(String str) {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * This printUddhav method is ..........
     *
     * @param strr
     */
    @Override
    public void printUddhav(String strr) {

    }

    @Override
    public void printGautam(String strr) {

    }
```

**Click on myInterface, you will be redirected to your method on the interface.**

Comment: That seems like a lot of manual work when compared to jautodoc. There you can put in all the javadoc headers in an entire file with a single keypress